# How to create 2 level nested map from SOQL query?

Tags: apex, map

```
List<QuoteLineItem> childQLIs = [Select id, category__c, Parent_Quote__c, Product2Id, PricebookEntryId, Quantity, Product2Id From QuoteLineItem]; 

 Map<Id,Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>> OuterMap = New Map<Id,Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>>();

 Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>> InnerMap = New Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>();

        for(QuoteLineItem childQLI: childQLIs) {
            if(InnerMap.containsKey(childQLI.category__c){
                InnerMap.get(childQLI.category__c).add(childQLI);
            } 
            else {
                InnerMap.put(childQLI.category__c, new List<QuoteLineItem> { childQLI });
            }
        }
```

Now my requirement is to wrap this map further with the Parent_Quote__c field. Trying to achieve a map--

```
Map<Id,Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>> OuterMap and need to do OuterMap.put(Parent_Quote__c, InnerMap);
```

Comment: Consider just using a separate wrapper `class` or classes to build out something of this complexity.  In general, anytime you're nesting a Map within a Map, consider wrapper classes instead

Comment: Thanks Brian, Any pointers for class for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare innermap within for loop and assign it to either an existing entry in outer map or new map if not already existing.

```
List<QuoteLineItem> childQLIs = [Select id, category__c, Parent_Quote__c, Product2Id, PricebookEntryId, Quantity, Product2Id From QuoteLineItem]; 

 Map<Id,Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>> OuterMap = New Map<Id,Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>>();



        for(QuoteLineItem childQLI: childQLIs) {
             Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>> InnerMap;
            if(OuterMap.containsKey(childQLI.Parent_Quote__c)){
                 innerMap = OuterMap.get(childQLI.parent_Quote__c);
            }else
                 innerMap = New Map<String,List<QuoteLineItem>>();
            }
            if(InnerMap.containsKey(childQLI.category__c){
                InnerMap.get(childQLI.category__c).add(childQLI);
            } 
            else {
                InnerMap.put(childQLI.category__c, new List<QuoteLineItem> { childQLI });
            }
            OuterMap.put(childQLI.Parent_Quote__c, innerMap);
        }
```